# @font-face not working on iphone/ipad

Tags: svg, mobile-safari, font-face, mime-types

I downloaded two font kits from Font Squirrel, and they work everywhere except on iphone/ipad.  This makes me think there is a problem with the svg file.

I have another font downloaded from font squirrel on a separate site (through the same host) that is working great on my mobile devices, and I cannot see what the difference is between them that would make the font work on one site but not another.

My host recognizes svg (says so here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MIME_Types), so i don't think it is a problem with the MIME type.  i don't know much about this though and might be missing something.

I have also checked the id in my svg files, and they match the #id in my @font-face declarations:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OswaldStencilRegular';
    src: url('Oswald-Stencil-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Oswald-Stencil-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Oswald-Stencil-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Oswald-Stencil-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Oswald-Stencil-webfont.svg#OswaldStencilRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be here?

Comment: Have you tried @font-face rules that only contain a single format, to see which ones work? Put your example online somewhere?

Comment: thank you for responding!  the fonts are on [link](shufordlandscapeconstruction.com). i have tried as you suggested, but i must be doing something wrong. even if i take out the entire @font-face declaration, it still works on my laptop, which i didn't expect to happen...do i need to remove the format files i have uploaded as well?

Comment: All the fonts are missing (404's), which may be because your paths in the @font-face src are wrong or because the files are simply not there on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It was a problem with the paths.  I need ed to make them go up a directory.

Comment: Please post an answer if you resolved the problem. Regarding it still working after you remove the entire @font-face declaration, your stylesheet was cached. Clear your cache, use private browsing, or do a hard refresh to see your changes next time.